# No applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, lapply, tidyr

I have four dataframes in my environment, each with a first column that looks like this:

```
      product.consom.unit.tax.currency.geo.time
1                 6000,4161901,KWH,I_TAX,EUR,AL
2                 6000,4161901,KWH,I_TAX,EUR,AT
3                 6000,4161901,KWH,I_TAX,EUR,BA
4                 6000,4161901,KWH,I_TAX,EUR,BE
5                 6000,4161901,KWH,I_TAX,EUR,BG
6                 6000,4161901,KWH,I_TAX,EUR,CY
```

I want separate the first column into multiple columns using the tidyr `separate`:

```
data <- list(c("df1", "df2", "df3", "df4"))
sep <- function(x){
  x <- separate(x, 1, c("prod", "band", "unit", "tax", "currency", "geo"), ",", remove = TRUE)
}
lapply(data, sep)
```

When I run the `lapply` i get the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("separate_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "character"

Any and all help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why not just read it as a csv file?

Comment: You are trying to separate the character vector `c("df1", "df2", "df3", "df4")`, which isn't possible. You need a list of data frames.

Comment: @gersht Is spot on. You should call your actual dataset name not a character vector ie `df1` not `"df1"`.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments under your post have pointed out the problem. I provide a solution combining `lapply()` and `list2env()` to achieve what you want:

```r
library(tidyr)
data <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
names(data) <- paste0("df", 1:4)
list2env(lapply(data, separate, 1, c("prod", "band", "unit", "tax", "currency", "geo"), ","), .GlobalEnv)
```

(The argument `remove` in `separate()` defaults to `TRUE`, so I ignore it.)

`df1` to `df4` in the workspace will be overwritten to the separated forms.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works once on my machine once I changed the `data <- list(c("df1", "df2", "df3", "df4"))` into `data <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)` as suggested by @gersht and  @NelsonGon. You need to remove `c()` as well.

I have also tried a `for loop` approach:

```
df1 <- data.frame(product.consom.unit.tax.currency.geo.time = c( 
            "6000,4161901,KWH,I_TAX,EUR,AL",
           "6000,4161901,KWH,I_TAX,EUR,AT",
             "6000,4161901,KWH,I_TAX,EUR,BA",
             "6000,4161901,KWH,I_TAX,EUR,BE",
             "6000,4161901,KWH,I_TAX,EUR,BG",
             "6000,4161901,KWH,I_TAX,EUR,CY"))
df2 <- df3 <- df4 <- df1
data <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

library(tidyr)
for (i in 1:4) {
  assign(paste0("df", i), separate(data.frame(data[i]), 1, c("prod", "band", "unit", "tax", "currency", "geo"), ",", remove = TRUE)) 
}
```